# ax integration error : SecurityNegotiationException was caught A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception

Tags: web-services, axapta

Error SecurityNegotiationException was caught

A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.

when integrate ax 2012 in c# application by call ledgerservice from visual studio 2010
and the service is called successfully
this is the code :

```
try
    {
  NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
    binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
   // binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0,10,0);
   // binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
   //// binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
   // binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
    //EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://apserver:8201/DynamicsAx/Services/LedgerServices");


    GeneralJournalServiceClient client = new GeneralJournalServiceClient();
    //binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None;
    client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel =
    System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
   /* CallContext context = new CallContext();*/

    client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "elsedawy";
    client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "administrator";
    client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "P@ssw0rd";


    //context.Company = "sdwy";

    AxdLedgerGeneralJournal journal = new AxdLedgerGeneralJournal();

    AxdEntity_LedgerJournalTable journalHeader = new AxdEntity_LedgerJournalTable();

    journalHeader.JournalName = "Vendor Inv";
    journalHeader.Name = "Vendor Inv";

    AxdEntity_LedgerJournalTrans journalLine = new AxdEntity_LedgerJournalTrans();

    journalLine.AccountType = AxdEnum_LedgerJournalACType.Ledger;

    journalLine.AccountTypeSpecified = true;

    journalLine.Company = "sdwy";

    AxdType_MultiTypeAccount account = new AxdType_MultiTypeAccount();

    account.Account = "12.01.01.103";

    account.DisplayValue = "RTL Cash Tayran";


    AxdType_DimensionAttributeValue dimValue1 = new AxdType_DimensionAttributeValue();

    dimValue1.Name = "MainAccount";

    dimValue1.Value = "5637144583";

   /* AxdType_DimensionAttributeValue dimValue2 = new AxdType_DimensionAttributeValue();

    dimValue2.Name = "MainAccount";

    dimValue2.Value = "5637144583";

    AxdType_DimensionAttributeValue dimValue3 = new AxdType_DimensionAttributeValue();

    dimValue3.Name = "CostCenter";

    dimValue3.Value = "5637145326";*/


    account.Values = new AxdType_DimensionAttributeValue[1] { dimValue1/*, dimValue2, dimValue3*/ };

    journalLine.LedgerDimension = account;

    journalLine.AmountCurDebit = 120;

    journalLine.AmountCurDebitSpecified = true;

    journalHeader.LedgerJournalTrans = new AxdEntity_LedgerJournalTrans[1] { journalLine };

    journal.LedgerJournalTable = new AxdEntity_LedgerJournalTable[1] { journalHeader };



    client.create(null, journal);
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string error = ex.Message;
    }
```

Comment: What is the question? What is the failing line?

Comment: Try running VS as administrator.